# Value duplicated in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The following is my code:

```
test = [{'name' : 'one'}, {'name' : 'two'}]

a = {}
b = []
c = {}
for i in test:
     c['name'] = i['name']
     b.append(c)
a['items'] = b
print(a)
```

This produces the following content of dictionary `a`, which is wrong:

```
{'items': [{'name': 'two'}, {'name': 'two'}]}
```

Why does the output dictionary, `a`, contains the value `'two'` twice and not 1 time the value `'one'` and 1 time the value `'two'`?

Comment: Because it's the same object...

Answer (score 0):

You only created *one* `dict` named `c`, so it's `name` key changes each time through the loop. You want a *new* `dict` to append to `b` each time through the loop: move `c = {}` *into* the loop's body.

```
for i in test:
    c = {}
    c['name'] = i['name']
    b.append(c)
```

or

```
for i in test:
    c = {'name': i['name']}
    b.append(c)
```

or

```
b = [{'name': i['name']} for i in test]
```

Comment: that did solve the problem but I still don't understand why it should matter, I added a print(b) after appending to see what's happening and this is the result  [{'name': 'one'}]
[{'name': 'two'}, {'name': 'two'}] it did append {'name' : 'one'} initially but in the next iteration changed both the values I don't understand why it changed the already appended one

Comment: it appended [{'name': 'one'}]  first and in the second iteration it changed to [{'name': 'two'}, {'name': 'two'}] I dont understand that

Comment: `b.append` does not add a *copy* of `c` to the list; it just adds the same reference over and over again. You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. (`c`, `b[0]`, b`[1]`, etc, all refer to the same object. Change it through one variable, and the changes are visible from *all* of them.)